# flutter error when I do future http.get and return body value the console log dont stop

Tags: flutter, http, logging, get, future

the log not stop

[image]
I run this code and the console log is like this

[image]

how can I fix it?
I want console log just one time

the getCrewInfo() called here
[image]

[image]

Comment: where and how did you call `getCrewInfo()` in your code?

probably , you call it inside loop function

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text. For more information, please see the Meta FAQ entry [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors/285557#285557)

Answer (score 0):

You should check the code again, which code that called the CrewInfoAPI? if you havent solved the problem, you may have to update more details on the question.

[image: recall]